# Using `noindex` for recently purchased domain we are migrating to

Tags: seo, search-engine-indexing, noindex

We recently purchased the `.com` version of our domain. So we are migrating from `oursite.org` to `oursite.com`, but this will take several weeks.

The site was previously indexed, and a Google search continues to show the previous content.

**Should we block search indexing of the site with `noindex` until we are ready for the site to go live?** If this has a lasting negative impact on the site SEO, I would prefer not to do that.

Comment: Is there going to be anything to index on the new site? Or is the migration going to take a while and as such there will be duplicate content on both?

Comment: @Squiggs. question is spot on. If there's going to be duplicated content for a certain time then you should not index the new site until the old on is down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're moving all your pages/content to the new domain (swapping .org for .com with the same url structure), you should definitely keep it "under the radar" until you have set all the correct redirects from the old domain to the new one.
So, add some "Under construction" or "Coming soon" to the new domain, block the search engines from indexing (either with noindex, or through robots, or set a password) the new domain. Sooner you do this, the sooner will search engines "forget" about the old content that is still showing there, which is also good for you.
Further more, make sure to follow all the best SEO practices when it comes to domain transfer, and don't just leave this to the developers.
Good luck!